# Growth of log, squar and power functions using Asymptotic Notation

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

Arrange the functions according to growth rate using Asymptotic Notation.

Can someone confirm whether the below listed sequence in ascending order is true or false ?

**n<sup>0.01</sup>, squareroot(n),6nlogn,4n<sup>3/2</sup>,2n log<sup>2</sup> n,4<sup>logn</sup>, n <sup>2</sup> (logn).**

Comment: Can anyone answer this please ??

Comment: I got the answer...        
n^0.01, squareroot(n),
6nlogn,    
2n (log^2 n), 4(n^3/2),

4^(logn), 
n ^ 2 (logn).

Answer (score 1):

This facts could helps:

1. squareroot(n) = n<sup>1/2</sup>
2. O(n<sup>1/2</sup>) > O(log(n))
3. when k is a constant number O(kn) = O(n)
4. 4<sup>log n</sup> = (2<sup>log n</sup>) <sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup>

so you have this order :

***n<sup>0.01</sup>, squareroot(n), 6n log n, 2n log<sup>2</sup> n, 4n<sup>3/2</sup>, 4<sup>logn</sup>, n <sup>2</sup> logn***